# laravel 7 keeps adding '/public/' to my api routes

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, request

I am trying to make a php curl request to my laravel api

Here's the curl function

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Accept:application/json', 'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest' )
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    print curl_error($curl);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

Here's where I call it :

```
    require_once ADJEMINPAY_PLUGIN_DIR.'includes/class-adjeminpay-functions.php';

    $url = "https://api.adjeminpay.net/v1/auth/getToken/";
    $postData = array(
        'firstName' => 'Lady',
        'lastName'  => 'Gaga',
        'submit'    => 'ok'
    );
    

    $result = CallAPI("POST", $url, $postData);

    var_dump($result);
```

Here's the result :

```
string(454) "HTTP/2 301 date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 12:12:03 GMT server: Apache location: https://api.adjeminpay.net/public/v1/auth/getToken content-length: 258 content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Moved Permanently
The document has moved here.

"
```

Looks like laravel doesn't get that it's an api request and keeps changing the url to https://api.adjeminpay.net/ **public/** v1/auth/getToken/ ; it also tries to redirect to https://api.adjeminpay.net/

Help kudasai TT

Comment: Did you set your webserver root to be the `public` directory? Did you set a correct `APP_URL` in your `.env`? (Btw, the `public` folder also shows up when using "Se connecter" at the top)

Comment: If you are making API in Laravel, first thing is it should be inside `routes/api.php` instead of `routes/web.php`. This would add `/api` to the route though but it should be tweakable.

Comment: @nice_dev My api routes are in routes/api.php I just tweaked it to be /v1 instead of /api because we plan on developping a v2 soon

Comment: @brombeer yes and yes, .env : ```APP_URL=https://api.adjeminpay.net/``` 
When u click "Se connecter" it redirects to another subdomain, and yeah the '/public' in the url is there, but till now it didn't cause any error in the other apis

Comment: It works fine when I do the same api requests with ajax, even with curl in command line it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, turns out the syntax/version of curl I was using was defective/uncomplete.

Went over to PostMan and executed the same request then copipasted the php -curl code which looks like this :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'yourUrl',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "apikey": "qsmdlfjqs",
    "application_id": "qsdlfqsmlj",
    "grant-type": "qmdsfqsdf"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    ': ',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

And it works fine now.
Arigathanks \(^^)/

By the way [How to generate PHP -curl code from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRlE6.png).